# Why does this return undefined?

Tags: javascript

```
var TTT = {
        canvas      : document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx         : canvas.getContext('2d'),
        cH          : 600,
        cW          : 600,
        // tile dimensions
        tH          : this.cH / 3,
        tW          : this.cW / 3
    };

// returns undefined... why? 
console.log(TTT.tH);
```

This got to be something very simple, but I can't seem to grasp why this is undefined...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you set `TTT.tH` and `tW`, `this` refers to the surrounding context, not the object itself. You can't set it to `TTT.cH` at the moment either, because it's not defined yet. What you can do is set them after the object is initially defined.

```
var TTT = {
        canvas      : document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx         : canvas.getContext('2d'),
        cH          : 600,
        cW          : 600
    };

// tile dimensions
TTT.tH = TTT.cH / 3;
TTT.tW = TTT.cW / 3;

// returns undefined... why? 
console.log(TTT.tH);
```

EDIT: As pointed out in a comment by Oriol, you'll need to do this as well for `TTT.ctx`, as `canvas` isn't defined yet.

Comment: +1, but I think he wanted to refer to the properties of the same object, in that case he should use the object name (TTT) instead of `this`.

Comment: And probably `TTT.ctx` should be set like `TTT.ctx = TTT.canvas.getContext('2d')`

Comment: @fardjad Oops, just missed that. Fixed now. :)

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Great explanation. Is this the proper way to define properties in an object like this? It seems to me it would be a lot more clear and reusable to put it in the TTT object directly...

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer i posted [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26574382/3187556), there's a second, completely different way of doing it. That's by using [getters and setters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects#Defining_getters_and_setters).

If you don't care about being able to reset `TTT.tH` and `TTT.tW` at a later point, you can just define them as getters:

```
var TTT = {
        canvas      : document.getElementById('canvas'),
        ctx         : canvas.getContext('2d'),
        cH          : 600,
        cW          : 600,
        // tile dimensions
        get tH() { return this.cH / 3 },
        get tW() { return this.cW / 3 }
    };

// returns undefined... why? 
console.log(TTT.tH);
```

Here, it's defined as a function, and so `this` will indeed work there.

Comment: Yes! This seems much more tidy to me. didn't know you could use getters and setters in javascript like this.

Comment: This may provide a good solution but it doesn't answer the question.